# Invoke method (that takes string param) on string via chaining

Tags: javascript

Can I do something like this?

```
var mystring = "http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F";

var mydecodedstring = mystring.apply(decodeURIComponent);
```

I know I can do this

```
var mydecodedstring = decodeURIComponent(mystring);
```

But I'd like to chain this if possible for syntactic purposes. Just curious if it's possible. My goal is:

```
mystring.?????
```

Comment: If you're looking to create a custom `String.method`, take a look at [String.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype). There is a good article about Method Chaining and using prototype [here](https://schier.co/blog/2013/11/14/method-chaining-in-javascript.html).

Comment: Is adding a String method the only way to do this? There's not an existing method that can accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, adding a method to the prototype method is the only way to do this (if you don't want to write something like `$(mystring).apply(decodeURIComponent)`), and that is [something you really should not do](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/1048572).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to see how apply works. You could do something like:

```
var mystring = "http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F";

var mydecodedstring = decodeURIComponent.apply(null, mystring);
```

Clearly, apply will not provide what you are looking for.

You could define your own function on the String prototype for decoding or define it only on your object.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to add a new method to String object?

```
 String.prototype.apply= function(entry){
     return decodeURIComponent(entry);
    }
    var mystring = "http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F";

    var mydecodedstring = mystring.apply(decodeURIComponent);
```